# WPF Converter JSON string to multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I've already made a workaround for this problem because of time constraints at work, although I still want to ask for learning purposes.

So I had this issue where I was making an editor screen for some record data, and in this record was a field called 'Quantity'. However, when designed, it was made a quantity placeholder, but it meant different things. So to explain, it is a SkuReference table, that has a 'Type' that defines if it's a 'Quantity per Pack', 'Roll Length', or 'CBC'. Well, for 'Quantity per Pack' and 'Roll Length', a simple number works, however for the 'CBC' (meaning, Corners/Borders/Centers) the data is stored as a JSON string object:

```
{ 'Corners': 10, 'Borders': 20, 'Centers': 30 }
```

Now on the WPF screen, if the data is identified as a 'CBC', I route the data to three textboxes, all bound to the 'Quantity' property of the parent object and using a converter and parameters to identify each one and I put the appropriate value into each textbox. Works fine.

The problem I have is when trying to work the ConvertBack part of the converter. I realized that I do not have reference to the original string property that I can edit and supply the new value to, or access to the other textboxes to just rebuild a new string to return. I was trying to come up with a resolution maybe using MultiBinding in my head, but could not completely come through with an answer.

Is this even possible? BTW I ended up just creating new properties that were split up and when the parent object was set parsed and passed around data. However, for future reference it would seem cleaner to me to just use the original data and a converter without the extra work.

Below is other code for reference:

**XAML, UpsertSkuReference.Quantity is the JSON string above**

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="5">
            <TextBlock Text="CBC" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="30" Text="{Binding UpsertSkuReference.Quantity, ConverterParameter=co, Converter={StaticResource CBCToIndividualConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding CBCIsChecked}" />
                <TextBox Width="30" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding UpsertSkuReference.Quantity, ConverterParameter=b, Converter={StaticResource CBCToIndividualConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding CBCIsChecked}" />
                <TextBox Width="30" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding UpsertSkuReference.Quantity, ConverterParameter=ce, Converter={StaticResource CBCToIndividualConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding CBCIsChecked}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

**Converter**

```
public class CBCToIndividualConverter : IValueConverter
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //--value = CBC JSON object string
        //--parameter = [co]: Corners, [b]: Borders, [ce]: Centers
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (parameter == null) { throw new Exception("CBCToIndividualConverter: parameter cannot be null"); }
            if (new string[] { "co", "b", "ce" }.Contains(parameter.ToString().ToLower()) == false)
            { throw new Exception("CBCToIndividualConverter: parameter must be 'co' for Corners, 'b' for Borders, or 'ce' for Centers"); }

            CornerBorderCenterModel cbc = json.Deserialize<CornerBorderCenterModel>(value.ToString());

            switch (parameter.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                case "co": { return cbc.Corners; }
                case "b": { return cbc.Borders; }
                case "ce": { return cbc.Centers; }
                default: { return null; }
            }
        }
        else { return null; }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            //--value = number for parameter type
            //--parameter = [co]: Corners, [b]: Borders, [ce]: Centers

            //--?? Uh Oh
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converters are not supposed to be used like that. There are cleaner ways. I would suggest you a slight bigger refactoring:

- Create 3 properties: `Borders`, `Corners` and `Centers`, on the class that contains the string `Quantity` (`SkuReference`?);
- When you set any of them, update the `Quantity`; when you update the `Quantity`, you try to parse in a `CornerBorderCenterModel` instance and then update the 3 properties with the values of this instance. All this work is doing implementing the `OnPropertyChanged` method (see my code later);
- In the view, bind every `TextBox` just with the relative property. This way, you need no converter at all (this works if the external `DataContext` is the instance of `UpsertSkuReference`; otherwise, you have to set the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` this way: `DataContext="{Binding UpsertSkuReference}"`, so the bindings of the 3 `TextBoxes` can find the properties on the object.

The whole round:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace XXX
{
    public class CornerBorderCenterModel
    {
        public int Corners { get; set; }
        public int Borders { get; set; }
        public int Centers { get; set; }
    }

    public class SkuReference : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        static JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        private static string[] _jsonStringParts =
            new[] { nameof(Borders), nameof(Corners), nameof(Centers) };

        public SkuReference()
        {
            PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        public int Corners
        {
            get { return _Corners; }
            set
            {
                if (_Corners != value)
                {
                    _Corners = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private int _Corners;

        public int Borders
        {
            get { return _Borders; }
            set
            {
                if (_Borders != value)
                {
                    _Borders = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private int _Borders;

        public int Centers
        {
            get { return _Centers; }
            set
            {
                if (_Centers != value)
                {
                    _Centers = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private int _Centers;

        private void UpdateCBCFromQuantity()
        {
            //if Quantity is a CBC and is not null do the following:

            var cbc = json.Deserialize<CornerBorderCenterModel>(_Quantity.ToString());

            if (cbc != null)
            {
                Corners = cbc.Corners;
                Borders = cbc.Borders;
                Centers = cbc.Centers;
            }
        }

        public string Quantity
        {
            get { return _Quantity; }
            set
            {
                if (_Quantity != value)
                {
                    _Quantity = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private string _Quantity;

        private void UpdateJsonStringFromCBC()
        {
            Quantity = string.Format(
                "{{ 'Corners': {0}, 'Borders': {1}, 'Centers': {2} }}",
                _Corners,
                _Borders,
                _Centers);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_jsonStringParts.Contains(e.PropertyName))
                UpdateJsonStringFromCBC();

            else if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Quantity))
                UpdateCBCFromQuantity();
        }
    }
}


<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding UpsertSkuReference}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Corners}" IsEnabled="{Binding CBCIsChecked}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Borders}" IsEnabled="{Binding CBCIsChecked}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Centers}" IsEnabled="{Binding CBCIsChecked}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Note that `Quantity`, `Borders`, `Corners` and `Centers` must raise notifications when they changed (just as I made, or using more advanced tools like the Reactive library), otherwise the whole round can't work.

Comment: This is pretty close to the work around I used since I couldn't wait, except that when any of the properties were changed it would rebuild the parent json string. I guess it's not possible the way I was going. At first I thought it was a neat way of doing things, and works beautifully going down, but just cant come back up.